# change pitch track colour

Tags: pitch, praat

I want to draw the pitch track based on a `Text-Grid` annotated sound object.

I call the `TextGrid` and the Pitch file and use the following code to get the 
textgrid and the pitch extracted.

```
   Read from file... 'textDir$'\'baseFile$'.TextGrid
   Read from file... 'soundDir$'\'baseFile$'.wav

   To Pitch (ac): 0.005, 75, 15, "no", 0.1, 0.45, 0.01, 0.35, 0.14, 600

     Times
     Font size... 20
     Black

select TextGrid 'baseFile$'
     plus Pitch 'baseFile$'
    Draw separately (semitones): 0, 0, -5, 15, "yes", "yes", "yes"
```

That works fine. However, I want to change the thickness of the pitch curve and 
also possible the color.

**Any idea how that can be done?**

Answer (score 0):

In the Praat Picture window, go to the `Pen` menu. Select your line width, and colour from the list.  Then run the Draw command again.